# Getting bad minute error from crontab despite seemingly accurate syntax

Tags: linux, cron, kubernetes-cronjob

Not sure what's going on as this cronjob is pretty straighforward. I want my cronjob to run every 5 minutes. Below is the script (memory.sh) in it's entirety.

Below that is the schedule it's requested to run on via the crontab.

I've replicated the crontab and run `crontab memory.sh` both under my username and as root, but each time I get the same error:

```
"/opt/memory.sh":4: bad minute
errors in crontab file, can't install.
```

**memory.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

now=`date +%Y-%m-%d.%H:%M:%S`

echo "$now" >>/opt/memory.out
ps aux --sort -rss>> /opt/memory.out


echo "$now" >>/opt/memory_free.out
free -m>> /opt/memory_free.out
```

**crontab**

```
# Edit this file to introduce tasks to be run by cron.
#
# Each task to run has to be defined through a single line
# indicating with different fields when the task will be run
# and what command to run for the task
#
# To define the time you can provide concrete values for
# minute (m), hour (h), day of month (dom), month (mon),
# and day of week (dow) or use '*' in these fields (for 'any').#
# Notice that tasks will be started based on the cron's system
# daemon's notion of time and timezones.
#
# Output of the crontab jobs (including errors) is sent through
# email to the user the crontab file belongs to (unless redirected).
#
# For example, you can run a backup of all your user accounts
# at 5 a.m every week with:
# 0 5 * * 1 tar -zcf /var/backups/home.tgz /home/
#
# For more information see the manual pages of crontab(5) and cron(8)
#
# m h  dom mon dow   command*
*/5 * * * * /opt/memory.sh
```

**directory**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`crontab memory.sh` installs a new crontab file.  `memory.sh` is not a crontab, it is a script references from the crontab file.  You need to pass the crontab file to the `crontab` command, or edit the existing file using `crontab -e` to add the line you indicated.

Comment: Not sure I'm following. The code pasted under my `crontab` section is what comes up when I input `crontab -e`. It was originally blank until I added the schedule/command you see on the final line. I then try to run `crontab memory.sh` from the command line and get the bad minute error. Is there something different/further I need to do?

Comment: You don't need to run `crontab memory.sh` if you have edited the crontab using the `-e` option. What are you attempting to do with this command?

Comment: I see. I want the script to run every 5 minutes and run a quick memory profile. I've set it to output a file `memory.out` in the `/opt` folder, but I'm not seeing anything (I set it to run yesterday morning)